# tikz parallel foreach

Tags: expl3, foreach, pgfkeys

I have seen the solution in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193846/201158)

```
\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{evaluate=#3 as #1 using {{#2}[#3-1]}},
}
```

but there is a bug: when all lists both have only one item, it will not work as expected. The reason is in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/547328/201158).

So I try to introduce latex3 to make it bug free.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_list_clist
\NewDocumentCommand {\getitem} {m O{1}} {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_list_clist #1
  \clist_item:Nn \g_list_clist {#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{
    evaluate=#3 as #1 using "before\getitem{#2}[#3]"
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i [
    count = \c,
    parallel foreach = \x in {test} via \c,
  ] in {1}
    \node at (\i, 0) {blank\x};
  \node at (1, -1) {no blank\getitem{{test}}[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But there is a small problem: the item obtained in this way has **an extra blank space** before it. How to fix this problem? And why #1 doesn't need to be braced?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define `parallel foreach` as being a style with parameter text `#1in#2via#3`, with no spaces, and then you use:

```
parallel foreach = \x in {test} via \c
```

so the arguments to `parallel foreach` are `␣\x␣`, `␣{test}␣`, and `␣\c`, then when you pass it to `\getitem`, you have:

```
\clist_gset:Nn\g_list_clist␣{test}␣
```

The first space token is consumed by TeX when grabbing the second argument to `\clist_gset:Nn`, but the second space is typeset in your node.

There are several possibilities here, for instance `\tl_trim_spaces:n`:

```
\clist_gset:Nx \g_list_clist { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} }
```

(actually, the implementation is a bit more complicated to check for braces around the argument to `parallel foreach`; see the code at the bottom of this answer).  However `expl3` provides `\clist_item:nn`, so you can take items from a comma-separated list without storing it in a variable, which makes things simpler here:

```latex
\exp_args:Nx \clist_item:nn
  { \tl_trim_spaces:n {#1} } {#2}
```

Though this doesn't cope with the possibility of multiple items in the list because of the extra braces. You need to check if the argument to `parallel foreach` is within braces, and if so remove them, with something like:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand {\getitem} {m O{1}} {
  \exp_args:Nx \clist_item:nn
    { \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \zhiyuan_remove_braces:n } {#2}
}
\cs_new:Npn \zhiyuan_remove_braces:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
      { \exp_not:n #1 }
      { \exp_not:n {#1} }
  }
```

With that, your code produces the expected output:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\getitem} {m O{1}} {
  \exp_args:Nx \clist_item:nn
    { \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \zhiyuan_remove_braces:n } {#2}
}
\cs_new:Npn \zhiyuan_remove_braces:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
      { \exp_not:n #1 }
      { \exp_not:n {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{
    evaluate=#3 as #1 using "before\getitem{#2}[#3]"
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i [
    count = \c,
    parallel foreach = \x in {test,another} via \c,
  ] in {1,2}
    \node at (1, \i) {blank\x};
    \node at (1, -1) {no blank\getitem{{test}}[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the code using a `clist` variable rather than `\clist_item:nn`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_list_clist
\NewDocumentCommand {\getitem} {m O{1}} {
  \use:x
    {
      \clist_gset:Nx \exp_not:N \g_list_clist
        { \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \zhiyuan_remove_braces:n }
    }
  \clist_item:Nn \g_list_clist {#2}
}
\cs_new:Npn \zhiyuan_remove_braces:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
      { \exp_not:n #1 }
      { \exp_not:n {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfset{
  foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{
    evaluate=#3 as #1 using "before\getitem{#2}[#3]"
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i [
    count = \c,
    parallel foreach = \x in {test,another} via \c,
  ] in {1,2}
    \node at (1, \i) {blank\x};
    \node at (1, -1) {no blank\getitem{{test}}[1]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```