# Parallel looping through multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, for-loop

I do not know what is wrong with my code. The error message

```
 Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `red' (in '{ red,green,blue,purple
```

occurs during compiling this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% defining parallel looping
\pgfset{
   foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{
       evaluate=#3 as #1 using {{#2}[#3-1]}
   },
}

\begin{document}

   %% defining three array's
   \newcommand{\myArrayI}{Marco,Andrea,Kiara,Carmen,Sebastian,Kurt}
   \newcommand{\myArrayII}{33,26,2,45,18,41}
   \newcommand{\myArrayIII}{red,green,blue,purple,yellow,black}

   %% parallel looping
   \foreach \ia [count=\cnt,
                 parallel foreach=\ib in \myArrayII  via \cnt,
                 parallel foreach=\ic in \myArrayIII via \cnt]  in \myArrayI
                 {
                  iteration \cnt: \ia, \ib, \ic   \\        
                 }
          
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this help:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547541/tikz-parallel-foreach ?

Comment: @Cicada unfortunately not. But I could solve this by myself. See my reply below.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I could solve this problem by myself. I just added double quotes around each element in the third array `\myArrayIII` as follows.

```
\newcommand{\myArrayIII}{"red","green","blue","purple","yellow","black"}
```

And it works. See the complete code here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% defining parallel looping
\pgfset{
   foreach/parallel foreach/.style args={#1in#2via#3}{
       evaluate=#3 as #1 using {{#2}[#3-1]}
   },
}

\begin{document}

   %% defining three array's
   \newcommand{\myArrayI}{Marco,Andrea,Kiara,Carmen,Sebastian,Kurt}
   \newcommand{\myArrayII}{33,26,2,45,18,41}
   \newcommand{\myArrayIII}{"red","green","blue","purple","yellow","black"}

   %% parallel looping
   \foreach \ia [count=\cnt,
                 parallel foreach=\ib in \myArrayII  via \cnt,
                 parallel foreach=\ic in \myArrayIII via \cnt]  in \myArrayI
                 {
                  iteration \cnt: \ia, \ib, \ic   \\        
                 }
          
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]